# Not able to choose appropriate function

Tags: angularjs

```
 <div class="slideDown" ng-hide="!active1">
    <div class="expand-collapse-content">
      <a ng-href="{{activeUser.path.mail}}"
        ng-show="activeUser.path.mail.length"
        ng-disabled="baseURL.endsWith('/Mail/')"
        ng-click="mailbox.newMessage($event)">Email</a>

      <a ng-href="{{activeUser.path.contacts}}"
        ng-disabled="baseURL.endsWith('/Contacts/')"
        ng-click="addressbook.newComponent('card')">Contact</a>

      <a ng-href="{{activeUser.path.calendar}}"
        ng-show="activeUser.path.calendar.length"
        ng-disabled="baseURL.endsWith('/Calendar/')"
        ng-click="list.newComponent($event, 'appointment')">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to call the function from every page.
But in this case by using this code if I'm clicking on calendar from email page then it is redirected to calendar page but the new calendar function will not work...

After that if i'm again clicking to calendar then calendar will come nd goes automatically.

Comment: where is the function you wanna call, show your ctrl/component code pls.

Comment: the code which i have write in ng-click are the functions in the above code